# AWS Lambda returns an error while localhost shows the result

Tags: json, node.js, aws-lambda

```
let msg:string[] = ['a','b']; 
export const flight = async (event, context, callback) => { 
const responsee = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: msg,
        };
        callback(null, responsee);
}
```

This one works fine with localhost and when I deploy it in to AWS it returns an 'Internal Server Error'.

When I do stringify the string, It works fine in AWS and localhost.

```
const responsee = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(msg),
    };
```

Want to why the first code snippet returns an error in AWS.

Comment: what node version is your landa using? is `Internal server error` the only message?

Comment: Node version 6.11.4 and yes the only message is that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys refer to this page.

> result – is an optional parameter that you can use to provide the result of a successful function execution. The result provided must be JSON.stringify compatible. If an error is provided, this parameter is ignored.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

At my first time on lambda, I met this problem, this thing made me to confuse.

Comment: `{code: 200, message: ['a', 'b',] }` it is a `JSON.stringify` able unless there is something specific to the version they are running